# consuming SOAP web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am looking for some alternatives of consuming a SOAP web service in java. I am currently using a stub method to consume it and it's too simple for my instructor needs. My instructor said to do a trivial client, what was that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is basically the submission of XML to a web server using the POST method. While the XML can get verbose, you should be able to construct the XML using StringBuilder and then use a simple HTTP client, like the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to construct a POST request to a URL using 
the XML string as the body.

That's about as simple as they come.

Comment: I don't quite understand what a trivial client means though... so make the client as dumb as possible?

Comment: I would say that the instructor is trying to get you to not use a large framework and stick to the simple task of getting the minimum information to the server to invoke the service.

Comment: The HttpClient site has a directory of examples and one is PostSOAP. http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/

Comment: Is there a way to see the soap message that my stub client is sending to the service?

Comment: Use a intercept software like tcpmon on the endpoint to get a hold of the message.

Comment: @aherlambang : Yes, you can set a few properties if using Apache package, see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-enable-debug-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and lightweight example for consuming the soap api. Steps are below.

1. You must create the SOAPTestController.java, KflConstants.java And SoapClient.java class.
2. Then Implement the below code blocks and enjoy it.

Here is the **SOAPTestController.java** class

```
@Controller
public class SOAPTestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showdate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getDateAndTime() {

        String DateAndTimeSOAPRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n"
                + "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\r\n"
                + "  <soap12:Body>\r\n" + "    <GetDateAndTime xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />\r\n"
                + "  </soap12:Body>\r\n" + "</soap12:Envelope>";
        String Fundtion = "GetDateAndTime";
        return new SoapClient().ConsumeTheService(DateAndTimeSOAPRequest, "GetDateAndTime");
    }
}
```

This is the **KflConstants**.java class

```
public class KflConstants {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "http://192.168.0.222/";
    public static final String SERVICE_URL = SERVER_IP + "businesswebserviceNew/service.asmx";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_XML = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    public static final String GET_DATE_AND_TIME_URL = SERVICE_URL + "/GetDateAndTime";
}
```

Here is the **SOAPClient**.java class

```
public class SoapClient {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SoapClient.class);

    /*Input Stream Convert to the String Object*/
    public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    public String ConsumeTheService(String SOAPXML, String APINAME) {
        String Result = null;
        try {
            /*Create The Connection*/
            URL url = new URL(KflConstants.SERVICE_URL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", KflConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_XML);
            conn.setRequestProperty(APINAME, KflConstants.GET_DATE_AND_TIME_URL);
            log.info("Sending the envelope to server");
            /*Send the request XML*/
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(SOAPXML.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
            /* Read the response XML*/
            log.info("Reading the Response");
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            Result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            /*INput Stream Convert to the SOAP Message*/
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Result.getBytes());
            SOAPMessage resposeSOAP = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
            /*Return Values*/
            log.info("Result SOAP:"+resposeSOAP.toString());
            log.info("Result String:"+Result);
            return Result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

```
SoapRequestBuilder s = new SoapRequestBuilder();
s.Server = "127.0.0.1"; // server ip address or name

s.MethodName = "ConcatWithSpace";
s.XmlNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
s.WebServicePath = "/SimpleService/Service1.asmx";
s.SoapAction = s.XmlNamespace+s.MethodName;
s.AddParameter("one", "David");
s.AddParameter("two", "Hobbs");
String response = s.sendRequest();
```